Python Container Logs aren't Showing up in Google Cloud's Log Explorer
I'm trying to log a simple "hello world!" inside a python file which is being built as a Cloud run job container. However, my logs are not showing up in the log explorer, although the job is being created with the container image that contains the logs.
Currently, my code inside the main.py of the container looks like this:

"""A workload image for cloud run jobs.

Logs hello world and times its creation and end time.
"""

import logging
import sys
import time


# logs to stderr will be automatically captured by cloud logging
# https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging#container-logs
logging.info("container_start_time: %s", time.time())
print("Hello World!!!")
logging.warning("container_end_time: %s", time.time())
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stderr.write("Gfoo\n")

Any of the logs in the code isn't showing up in Google Cloud's log explorer.
I've also tried:

using the client libraries found on this page:https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/samples/logging-stdlogging?hl=en
writing strucutred logs: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/samples/logging-write-log-entry?hl=en#logging_write_log_entry-python.
adding ENV PYTHONNUNBUFFERED=true to my dockerfile

I've also followed tips on: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html.
How can I resolve this issue? I appreciate your help! Thanks!

Update:
The real issue was with a GetOrBuild method I was using to build the image. The first version of my main.py had only logging.info, which does not appear in the log explorer. When I replaced it with a simple print, the logs showed up once I set the flag "force_container_build" to true. The flag forces image building even if it has been built previously.
So the issue for me was that the image was never refreshed/rebuilt after switching to print because the GetOrBuild method fetches the existing image if it was built once. So setting the force_container_build flag to true, solved the issue.
In summary: logging.info does not show up in the log explorer but print, sys.stderr, and logging.warning worked once the image was rebuilt.
